# Whitespace and margin inconsistency

Tags: html, css

I have made some html and css setup and for some reason the margin between the small divs, varies in width.

[image]

I don't know if that's also the reason to my next problem, but if you try to resize the window in width, I have made the setup, so that a new div is applied when there's enough space in width.

[image]

As you can see on the picture above, the top row applies `17px` margin between the two divs while the bottom row only has `14px` margin. This causes an issue that only the bottom row gets a new div applied.

I have made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z3d8M/ So that you can see the example of my code. You can see if you resize the window in width, that some of the sections get's a div applied before other sections, and I really wanted it to be even. hopefully without any kind of javascript involved.

**My CSS:**

```
/* CONTAINER */
.container {
    z-index:10;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top:50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: lightgrey;
}

    .container section.dsv {
        width:100%;
        background: red;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        position: relative;
        height: 340px;
    }

    .container section.dsv.landscape {
        height: 400px !important;
    }

    .container section.dsv .dsv_inner {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .title {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-left: 215px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

/* CARDS */
.card_list {
    margin-left: 215px;
    max-height: 320px;
    min-width: 680px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin:20px 10px 20px 215px
}

.landscape .card_list {
    max-height: 370px !important;
}

    .card_list .breaker {
            width:165px;
            margin:0 7px;
            height: 300px;
            display: inline-block;
            background: none;
            float: left;
        }

        .card_list .breaker.double {
            width:346px !important;
        }

.card_wrapper {
    margin:0 7px 20px 7px;
    width:165px;
    height: 300px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .landscape .card_wrapper {
        width: 346px !important;
        height: 170px !important;
        margin:0 7px 14px 7px;
    }
```

**My HTML:**

```
<!-- CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- category section -->
        <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum?</div>
        <section class="dsv" style="">
            <div class="dsv_inner">

                <div class="card_list">
                    <div class="breaker"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="title">Dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="card_list">
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
            <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- category section -->
        <div class="title">dipper dupper</div>
        <section class="dsv landscape" style="">
            <div class="dsv_inner">

                <div class="card_list">
                    <div class="breaker"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div><div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="card_wrapper"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now define your `parent` `.card_list` `font-size:0;` and **inner sub `div` define `font-size:12px; //` according to design**

as like this

```
.card_list{font-size:0;}
.card_list div{font-size:12px;}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3d8M/1/)**

Comment: To help stop the font-size rules cascading down too far perhaps add a child selector `.card_list > div`? may be wholly unnecessary, but given you are only aiming for the direct child it's probably worth doing yeah?

Comment: Amazing thanks! It solved everything.. A little weird that I have to define font-sizes like that. Can you link to any kind of CSS documentation that explains this behavior?

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted Now check to  this url http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hopefully people will find this interesting as well.